# Дайте теорию и задания по В1.

Tags: словообразование, егэ

Здравствуйте!

Решил готовиться к ЕГЭ так: учу теорию к конкретному заданию и делаю 50-70 заданий для закрепления навыка.

Напишите, пожалуйста, теорию, которую следует выучить для выполнения задания B1 по ЕГЭ, а так же, дайте ,пожалуйста, 50-100 егэшных заданий по этой теме(сообразование).

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похвально, хотя и поздновато. В помощь:

http://repetitor-russ.ru/ege-russkij-yazyk-zadanie-v1-sposoby-obrazovaniya-slov/

http://gramma.ru/EXM/?id=4.43

http://nsportal.ru/shkola/russkii-yazyk/library/zadaniya-po-slovoobrazovaniyu-trening-po-v1-ege

http://spisivay.ru/publ/22-1-0-326

http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/211

Comment: Какие то тематические книги хорошие есть?

Comment: Да в сборнике тестов Сениной есть всё: и теория, и практика. Есть прекрасная книга-репетитор С.Ивановой "Экзаменационные ловушки", только не знаю, переиздаётся ли она .

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри здесь. Ме нравится, толково все. [link text](http://uchimcauchitca.blogspot.ru/search/label/ЕГЭ%20В1%20Словообразование)